# jQuery only works in HTML file, not in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was just setting up jQuery (kinda new to jQuery scripting) but when I wanted to use it in my .js file, it didn't work. Later on I tried using jQuery in my HTML file using the  tags, but then it worked! I'd like to script in my .js file, so could anyone help me with this? Thanks!

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="test.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script>
        alert("My current jQuery version is "+jQuery.fn.jquery);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript file:

```
alert("I am running this from 'test.js'. My current version of jQuery is "+jQuery.fn.jquery);
```

Comment: `test.js` comes after `jQuery`

Comment: I think 9 down-votes is perhaps a little excessive on a newbie... Have added the example that was in pastebin directly to beef it out a little :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<head>
        <title>Test</title>


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js" ></script>

</head>

<body>
        <script>
                alert("My current jQuery version is "+jQuery.fn.jquery);
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

You are including your test.js script before jQuery...

```
   <script src="test.js" ></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Simply include it afterwards and then jQuery will exist :)

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="test.js" ></script>
```

Comment: @Reshun: Is there a reason you selected the later answer as the correct one? This answer was posted two minutes earlier (hover over the elapsed duration for actual time).